# How to select rows from a table using Jmeter webdriver sampler?

Tags: webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a table having some rows

I want to select rows one by one using JMeter webdriver sampler

I used below code unable to do

```
var tableIPRange=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('IPRangeGroup'))
var tableRows=WDS.browser.findElements(pkg.By.tagName('option'))
var rowIterator=tableRows.iterator()

while(rowIterator.hasNext())
{
    var row=rowIterator.next()
    WDS.log.info(row)
    row.click()
    var delRow=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('DeleteIPRangeId'))
    delRow.click()
    if(!rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the problem is. Assuming this is java code, why are there no semicolons?

Comment: This is Jmeter webdriver sampler plugin code.

Comment: So which programming language is it? Please add the relevant tag, maybe "javascript"?

Comment: It is not javascript. It is Jmeter specific code. For more information please refer http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered or http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are deleting row. When you delete element from webpage, you are required to refresh that list again.

You may want to try this.

```
var tableIPRange=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('IPRangeGroup'))
var tableRows=WDS.browser.findElements(pkg.By.tagName('option'))
var rowIterator=tableRows.iterator()

while(rowIterator.hasNext())
{
    var row=rowIterator.next()
    WDS.log.info(row)
    row.click()
    var delRow=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('DeleteIPRangeId'))
    delRow.click()
    tableIPRange=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('IPRangeGroup'))
    tableRows=WDS.browser.findElements(pkg.By.tagName('option'))
    if(!rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I could not able select the row itself from the table I suspect there is some thing I am doing wrong in var tableIPRange=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('IPRangeGroup'))
var tableRows=WDS.browser.findElements(pkg.By.tagName('option')) can you suggest me how to select a row from a table ?